# ibm rhapsody 7.6.1 generating a event in another class

Tags: rhapsody

I have two classes, a thermostat and a heater.  The association is an aggregation between both classes.

Now when I generate an event in class heater from class thermostat I get a Java null pointer error (run time error).

The code I used was `itsHeater.gen(new evHeaterOn())`.

Answer (score 1):

An aggregation generates a pointer. Unless you initialize that pointer then it will be pointing at null. Create a build class that instantiates your instances and initializes the pointers correctly.